# Buffers filled with unicode zeroes

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to synchronously read parameters from console in node, I managed to do the following:

```
var load = function () {
    const BUFFER_LENGTH = 1024;
    const stdin = fs.openSync('/dev/stdin', 'rs');
    const buffer = Buffer.alloc(BUFFER_LENGTH);
    console.log('Provide parameter: ');
    fs.readSync(stdin, buffer, 0, BUFFER_LENGTH);
    fs.closeSync(stdin);
    return buffer.toString().replace(/\n*/, '');
}
```

It works, but here's a strange thing:

```
var loadedValue = load();
console.log(loadedValue); // displays "a", if I typed "a", so the result is correct
console.log({loadedValue}); // displays {a: 'a\n\u0000\u0000....'}
```

When I wrap the value in an object, the remaining BUFFER bits are showed in a string. Why is that? How can I get rid of them? Regexp on a string before making an object doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Buffer.alloc(BUFFER_LENGTH)` creates a buffer of a particular length (1024 in your case), and fills that buffer with NULL characters (as documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_alloc_size_fill_encoding)).

Next, you read some (say 2) bytes from stdin into that buffer, which replaces the first two of those NULL characters with the characters read from stdin. The rest of the buffer still consists of NULL's.

If you don't truncate the buffer to the amount of bytes read, your function returns a buffer of length 1024, mostly filled with NULL's. Since those aren't printable, they don't show up in the first `console.log()`, but they're still there.

So after reading from stdin, you should truncate the buffer to the right size:

```
let bytesRead = fs.readSync(stdin, buffer, 0, BUFFER_LENGTH);
buffer = buffer.slice(0, bytesRead);
```